# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type') Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have such a problem when I launch storybook, this error appears in my localhost:6006 and I no longer know how to fix it

I have a problem when start storybook
[image]

I can't figure out what the error is

**stories.jsx**

```
export default {
  title: 'UI/Toast',
  argTypes: {
    toastType: {
      control: {
        type: 'select',
        options: [
         ...
        ],
      },
    },
...
  },
}

const Template = (args) => {
  toast.showToast(
    args.description,
    args.backgroundColor,
    args.padding,
    {
      type: args.toastType,
      position: args.toastPosition,
      autoDelete: args.toastIsAutoDelete,
      delay: args.toastAutoDeleteTime,
      animation: args.animation,
    },
  )
}

export const Default = Template.bind({})
Default.args = {
  ...
}
```

I use the singletone pattern to create notifications

**toastCreator.js**

```
let toastList = []
class ToastCreator {
  constructor(toastList) {
    if (ToastCreator.singleton) {
      return ToastCreator.singleton
    }

    ToastCreator.singleton = this
    this.toastList = toastList
  }

  getId() {
    return uuidv4()
  }

  getProp(text, padding, prop, backcolor) {
    const { toastId, type } = prop
    const [icon, backgroundColor, title, color] =
      getToastPropertiesByType(type)

    return {
      ...prop,
      id: toastId || this.getId(),
      description: text || 'Description',
      padding: padding || '',
      title: title,
      color: color,
      backgroundColor: backcolor || backgroundColor,
      icon: icon,
    }
  }

  showToast(text, backgroundColor, padding, prop) {
    const { position, autoDelete, delay, animation } = prop
    if (toastList.length < 3) {
      toastList = [
        ...toastList,
        this.getProp(text, backgroundColor, padding, prop),
      ]
    }

    return (
      <ToastPortal>
        <ToastContainer
          toastList={toastList}
          position={position}
          autoDelete={autoDelete}
          autoDeleteTime={delay}
          animation={animation}
          padding={padding}
        />
      </ToastPortal>
    )
  }
}
export const toast = new ToastCreator(toastList)
```

How I can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your argument order is wrong. You call `this.getProp(text, backgroundColor, padding, prop)` but the definition of that function is `getProp(text, padding, prop, backcolor)`. You should double check wherever `showToast` is called also has a matching order.

So you are passing `padding` as the `prop` argument. Since I guess this is undefined for some other reason (I cant say why thats the case since we'd need to see where `showToast` is called), its then trying to access properties on something which doesnt exist.

Change the call to match the order:

```
this.getProp(text, padding, prop, backgroundColor),
```